# Filter a condition after aggregate function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I've got database of flights and I want it to return average of delay, but I want it to **filter 'origin = 'SFO'' after counting average** of arr_delay_new.
If I use WHERE or HAVING it counts the average with condition origin = 'SFO'.
How to make it count avg first and filter later?

This one has no condition  origin = 'SFO'

```
SELECT A.airline_name, 
    AVG(F.arr_delay_new)
FROM Flight_delays F
JOIN Airlines A ON F.airline_id = A.airline_id
GROUP BY airline_name
ORDER BY AVG(arr_delay_new);
```

That's a result of this, but there obviously are some lines with origin != 'SFO'

```
Hawaiian Airlines Inc.: HA      4,20271940667491
Alaska Airlines Inc.: AS        7,45392753708848
Delta Air Lines Inc.: DL        12,2587876678628
Southwest Airlines Co.: WN      13,8239826054204
Virgin America: VX              13,9644670050761
SkyWest Airlines Inc.: OO       16,8082728044524
United Air Lines Inc.: UA       16,9504026008392
Spirit Air Lines: NK            18,0657512351061
American Airlines Inc.: AA      18,3753142444596
Frontier Airlines Inc.: F9      18,9802996961123
ExpressJet Airlines Inc.: EV    19,2545055411961
JetBlue Airways: B6             28,841148064491
```

If I use `where` or `having`:

```
SELECT airline_name, 
    AVG(arr_delay_new)
FROM Flight_delays F
JOIN Airlines A ON F.airline_id = A.airline_id
GROUP BY airline_name, origin
HAVING origin = 'SFO'
ORDER BY AVG(arr_delay_new); <code>
```

Result of the second has the condition origin = 'SFO', but the average is counted with this condition (**I want average of all flights not only with origin = 'SFO'**)

```
Hawaiian Airlines Inc.: HA  4,87096774193548
Delta Air Lines Inc.: DL    9,6353591160221
United Air Lines Inc.: UA   13,8158534305478
Alaska Airlines Inc.: AS    14,4591194968553
Virgin America: VX          15,7448055407565
SkyWest Airlines Inc.: OO   17,5338904363974
Southwest Airlines Co.: WN  17,866981769075
American Airlines Inc.: AA  18,3386824324324
JetBlue Airways: B6         21,2571942446043
Frontier Airlines Inc.: F9  26
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: I added results. I want the average to be like in first code but airlines like in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN origin = 'SFO' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put your query in sub-query and then apply conditional clause.

P.S I don't have points to comment.

Comment: So wait until you do have the points - don't add a bad answer.

Comment: Why not provide a complete answer i.e. show the entire query you are suggesting instead of just a suggestion on how to create it?